# A tricky probability question.

Tags: probability

I have been asked the following question, and unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed. Here is the question:

Suppose we have 99 empty papers and we wrote numbers from 1 to 99(using each number) on one side of the papers randomly. Then we mixed all the papers randomly and started to write numbers from 1 to 99 on the other sides (empty sides) of each paper randomly. What is the probability of having the same number on both sides of at least one paper?

Thanks!

Comment: It's related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox

Comment: @DVD : I don't think so. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The big difference between this and the birthday problem is that the birthday problem is you have a random group of people with a normal distribution of birthdays.  This you have a distinct  set of unique values.  It's more like (exactly like) the shuffled hat problem.  If memory serves me right about one third of the sheets of paper on average will have the same number.

Comment: normal distribution of birthdays? The dates are periodic and years are round...

Comment: @MichaelHardy or to probability of a fixed points in permutations, calculation of which, require inclusion/exclusion principle and the limit to infinity $\infty$, the base of natural logarithm $e.$  (@sol)

Comment: @fleablood : You say "a normal distribution of birthdays".  It is certain _not_ a normal distribution as the term "normal distribution" is normally understood in probability theory.  Conventionally in that problem one assumes a uniform distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In the birthday problem you have an arbitrary group of people with random assortment of birthdays.  I called that "normal".  If that was incorrect I'm willing to listen why.  This problem on the other hand is definately not normal; each value is represented exactly once.  No number is excluded and once a number is included it can never be represented again.  I see very little similarity between this and the birthday problem other then they are both probability problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** [Derangements](https://brilliant.org/wiki/derangements/).

**Hint:** Complement.

Comment: Sadly, I can't think of another way of counting it (other than using inclusion-exclusion to reprove the derangement formula) (+1).

Comment: @user64066 Just to be clear, do you understand what I said above? It's extremely skimpy on details, but would point you in the correct direction. You don't have to accept the answer, esp if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Could this be related with Fibonacci sequences? I tried to solve same problem for simple numbers like 4,5. For instance, when there are 4 papers, the probability is $5/8$ then nominator is $4+1$th of Fibonacci and the denominator is the next one. I have obtained similar things with other numbers.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Thanks for the hints. It is really useful!

Comment: @user64066 It's actually related to $e$. See the link that rob gave to derangements. You're likely looking at small cases, where there are a lot of Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Building off what's been said in the comments and answers, here's a solution using inclusion/exclusion. Hope this helps.

Let's let $X = \text{# of papers with matching numbers}$. Then $P\left(X\geq 1\right)$ is the probability that at least 1 paper has matching numbers.

Now, let $E_i = \left\{\text{$i$th paper has matching numbers}\right\}$. Then we have:

\begin{align*}
 P\left(X \geq 1\right) &= P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{99} E_i \right) \\[5pt]
 &= P\left(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3 \cup \dots \cup E_{99}\right) \\[5pt]
 &= \sum_{i} P\left(E_i\right) - \sum_{i<j}P\left(E_i \cap E_j\right) + \dots + (-1)^{99+1} P\left(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \dots \cap E_{99}\right) \\[5pt]
% &= N\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) - \binom{N}{2}\left(\frac{(N-2)!}{N!}\right) + \binom{N}{3}\left(\frac{(N-3)!}{N!}\right) - \dots +(-1)^{N+1}\left(\frac{1}{N!}\right)
\end{align*}

which comes from inclusion/exclusion.

Now, by symmetry we have that $P\left(E_1\right) = P\left(E_2\right) = \dots = P\left(E_{99}\right)$, and the same is true for the intersections in the inclusion/exclusion summations.

So the various probabilities we need in inclusion/exclusion are:

\begin{align*}
 P\left(E_i\right) &= \frac{1}{99} \\[5pt]
 P\left(E_i \cap E_j \right) &= \frac{1}{99}\times \frac{1}{98} \\[5pt]
 P\left(E_i \cap E_j \cap E_k \right) &= \frac{1}{99}\times \frac{1}{98} \times \frac{1}{97}  \\
 \vdots & \\
 P\left(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \dots \cap E_{99}\right) &= \frac{1}{99!}
\end{align*}

And there are $99$ different $E_i$'s, and $\binom{99}{k}$ intersections of size $k$. So, plugging into the inclusion/exclusion equation above we get:

\begin{align*}
 P\left(X \geq 1\right) &= P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{99} E_i \right) \\[5pt]
 &= 99\left(\frac{1}{99}\right) - \binom{99}{2}\left(\frac{1}{99\cdot 98}\right) + \binom{99}{3}\left(\frac{1}{99\cdot 98 \cdot 97}\right) - \dots +(-1)^{99+1}\left(\frac{1}{99!}\right) \\[5pt]
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{4!} + \dots + \frac{1}{99!} \\[5pt]
 &\approx 1 - e^{-1} 
\end{align*}

which comes from the Taylor series for $e^{x}$.

Note that the Taylor series is an infinite series and we are cutting it off at $\frac{1}{99!}$. However, since we have an alternating series we can also say that our error is less than the magnitude of the next term, i.e. error less than $\frac{1}{100!}$, so it's quite a good approximation.

Answer (score -2):

the answer is very simple . say in one piece of paper it is '5' chance that we end up  with wrong number on backside  out of 99 possible number is 98/99. if we write 5 ,we will be right. so chance of writing wrong number on backside in all 99 paper  is (98/99)^99 . so probability of at least one correct  = 1-(98/99)^99= 63.34%

Comment: This assumes that you are allowed to use any of the 99 numbers on the second paper (even the one already used on the first paper), whereas I think the intent is that you aren't allowed to repeat numbers.

Comment: Please improve your post by [formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) it. By using proper punctuation/grammar, as well as typesetting the maths properly, your answer is much more likely to be useful.